# How to call a Liferay calendar portlet from my own portlet

Tags: calendar, liferay

I have a requirement that i have to call the liferay calendar portlet from my portlet.Can anybody give me any idea that how it can be achieved?
I am doing this to my view.jsp

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/html/js/liferay/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Liferay.Widget({ url: 'http://localhost:8080/widget/web/guest/interview-availibility/-/calendar'});
</script>
```

but it is not working .Please somebody help

Comment: What version of liferay are you using?

Comment: 6.2 i am using ,do you have any example

Comment: I don't have any working example, but you can give following references a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options available for adding a portlet into another portlet.

**Using** `liferay-portlet:runtime`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>
<liferay-portlet:runtime name="8" instance="xxx" queryString="" />
```

OR

```
<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="_1_WAR_calendarportlet_" />
```

**Using** `liferay-ui:calendar`

```
<liferay-ui:calendar day="" year="" month="" />
```

**References:**
[**runtime-portlet**](http://www.liferay.com/web/barrie.selack/blog/-/blogs/embedding-a-portlet-in-web-content?_33_redirect=%2Fweb%2Fbarrie.selack%2Fblog%3Fp_p_id%3D33%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_33_struts_action%3D%252Fblogs%252Fview)
[**liferay-ui**](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/6810381)

Comment: should i write it in view.jsp

Comment: Yes, you can write it in JSP.

Comment: but it is not calling the portlet Prakash. I have retrived the javascript code that is generated for publishing the portlet to the web .I am posting.see my edited answer

Comment: Even the runtime portlet is showing unknown tag in the view.jsp

Comment: say one thing praksh how i will know the portletName of calendar portlet

Comment: and is that portletName is an example ?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can get it using renderResponse.getNamespace() http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/117962?_19_threadView=tree