# Display Liferay portlet inside other liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

I use Liferay portlet bundle 6.2 (Tomcat) and Liferay IDE(eclipse). I created two Liferay Plugin Project. In the first portlet(first plugin portlet), I save some data by using Portlet Preferences. Now, I will display second portlet in first portlet. How I can do that? I found this following code and this Link

[Open portlet from other portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134708/open-portlet-from-other-portlet)

```
    var url;
function createRenderURL(portletId) {       
AUI().ready('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
    var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
    renderURL.setName("test");       
    renderURL.setWindowState("pop_up"); 
    renderURL.setPortletId(portletId);           
    url = renderURL.toString();
});}
```

But, I don't unterstand this code? I add this code to view jsp, where I can found portletId? Please, can someone explain me this a little bit? I'm new in Liferay

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849978/how-to-call-a-liferay-calendar-portlet-from-my-own-portlet/31850867#31850867

Comment: Do you want to display portlet using popup or embed it in the same portlet?

Comment: I will to display portlet popup

Comment: Then you can get portletId from portlet table as suggested by @Kuroro

Comment: Then, I can add this code to view.jsp, and I invoke the method createRenderURL("..") in view.jsp, but what is here function(A)? How I write this method funktion(A)?

Comment: Yes, you can use this method in jsp. This is AUI scripting, just copy this as it is.

Comment: I invoked this with method with this button                                                                       <aui:button onClick="createRenderURL("customerpage_WAR_customerpageportlet");"   value="Show"></aui:button>.  But, I think I make a mistake?

Comment: thanks parkash and kuroro, I solved my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if your portlet is instanciable or not.

**Not instanciable:** your portletId should looks like **Weather_WAR_WeatherPortlet**

**Instanciable**: your portletId should looks like **Weather_WAR_WeatherPortlet_INSTANCE_5aSc**

You can check portletId on the table "portlet" inside your  database.

If you want to get it by programmation you should use PortletConfig class

```
((com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigImpl) portletConfig).getPortletId()
```

NB: portletId which are number are Liferay portlet